# Is it correct to send a 401 error before the user tries to login?

Tags: javascript, api, rest

In a REST Api i'm developing, someone told me to directly send a request to the "get current user (/me)" url without checking if there is a session token and simply redirect him to the login page when receiving a 401 response.

Is this correct? I thought that the browser should not receive a 4xx response unless the user does something he is not supposed to.

Comment: It's not wrong to send 400-class errors to a user. If they are unauthorized to access a certain resource, 401 is the correct error code

Comment: Yes but is it normal for the front-end to try to access a private resources if it knows the user is unauthentified?

Comment: @Sodium in front-end point of view it doesn't matter. All it cares about it preventing unauthorized user to access private data.

Comment: Do you have some examples of big business applications that do that? I've been checking some (Netflix, Paypal, Facebook, Google) and they don't do it. I have found one small website that proceeds that way but i wouldn't put it as a model about best api design practices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought that the browser should not receive a 4xx response unless the user does something he is not supposed to.

That's more restrictive than described by the standard, see [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5)

> The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client seems to have erred.

The server can't distinguish errors by the user from errors by the user agent - there's just a single HTTP request, that has to be judged of itself.

Another way of expressing the same idea: [REST's uniform interface constraint](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5) implies that clients with human users should be getting the same self descriptive responses as clients without human users.

Answer (score 0):

We do exactly this. We basically send a HTTP request, and if it comes back as a `401`, we know we need to log the user in.

We also send a `Link` header to tell the client where the user should go for log in:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Link: </login>; rel="authenticate"
```